# Nextjs router.push with anchor does not work

Tags: next.js, anchor, next-router

Do anyone have an idea of why adding an anchor does not necessary work ?

I have a page `/contracts` with a list of items.
Within each item (div) I put an unique ID
(example: `<div id="contract-3929 />`)

If I click on one item it redirects in a page detail `/contracts/detail` of this item, and then I have a left arrow "back" which is suppose to make me come back to the `/contracts` page with the list of items!
**I want to be able to scroll until the concerned item (contract) !**
So from detail page when I click on back button here is the code :

```js
const router = useRouter();
const goBackPage = () => {
    router.push(
      `/contracts#contract-${contract_id}`
    );
  };
```

For the record I have done exactly the same thing on another page and it works perfectly !
I also tried with `scroll:false` but still not working here.

```js
router.push(
      `/contracts#contract-${contract_id}`,
      undefined,
      { scroll: false }
    );
```

So I am wondering if this is the good way of doing it ?
Thx a lot

Comment: Did you solve this?